# height 100% in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, height

I'm having problems with a side `div` that won't get the height to 100% in Chrome. It works just fine in FF.

I'm using:

```
html, body {

 padding: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

}

#div {

    min-height: 100%; 
}
```

Why is that ?

Comment: You can't specify the dimensions of html and body. html isn't even a display element, and body contains ALL display elements

Comment: @Jamie Wong: Not true, if you don't specify html and body you can't get 100% height

Comment: @Diadistis Wrong I am - http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/7559.htm for reference

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works perfect for me on every browser :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>min-height test</title>
    <style type="text/css"> 
    html, body { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    #div { min-height: 100%; background-color: gray; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div">test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you provide more details?

**Edit**

Here is the updated version based on the provided information :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>min-height test</title>
    <style type="text/css"> 
    html, body { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 100%; text-align: center; }
    .contents { height: 100%; width: 780px; margin-left: auto;
                 margin-right: auto; text-align: left; }
    #right { float: left; width: 217px; min-height: 100%; background:#4b805b; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contents">
        <div id="right">test</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Still everything looks fine for Chrome, Firefox and IE8

Comment: i don't know what else to add this is all the css of the container
//I REALLY DONT KNOW HOW TO FORMAT THE CODE FOR STACKOVERFLOW SORRY ! 


    #right {
 float: left;
 width: 217px;
 min-height: 100%; 
 background:#4b805b;
    }

and this is the hole body/html

    html, body {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
   text-align: center; 
    }
    body {
 font-family: "Tahoma CE", "Arial CE", "Helvetica CE", Tahoma, Arial, lucida, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 background:url(images/bk.jpg) repeat-x fixed;
 
    }

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a minified version of the html. What matters is your html layout, not your CSS.

Comment: I really can't do that, i haven't written the code(which is a mess btw) i'm just the debugger (does the fact that the sidebar is included via php have something to do with this ? )

Comment: No, PHP doesn't affect anything. Just make sure that `#right` div is directly inside `body` and not inside some other container element. If it is then adjust your styles so each and every parent element has either `height: 100%;` or `min-height: 100%;`

Comment: .contents {
 height: 100%;
 width: 780px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
 text-align: left;
    }

so thats a yes

Comment: I have updated the sample based on your partial information. It works as expected. There must be something that you're missing. Please provide a sample, don't make us do all the work for you...

Comment: @andrei: You can copy-paste the HTML from your browser, just choose View > Page Source or something like that.

Comment: for me html, body { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; } did the trick. These two tags were limiting all their child divs.

Answer (score 10):

From http://doctype.com/give-two-nested-divs-100-minheight:

> The child element inherits the height
>   of the parent container only if it is
>   specified explicitly. But min-height
>   is not an explicit specification of
>   height, so the computed height is
>   "auto" and not 100%.

Comment: Wow, so the answer is to set both **height** and **min-height** to **100%**?  Or just **height** and leave **min-height** out?

Answer (score 5):

You have to specify your parent with 100% height as well as the child so

```
html,body{
     height: 100%;
}
#div{
      min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%; /*for IE*/
}
```

The !important will overwrite all other height rules. Try that you should have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check with Below code, working and Printing labels fine for me under `Zebra GC420d` label printer:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css"> 
    html, body { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    #div { min-height: 100%; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="border: 0px solid red;">
    <table border="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
    <?php
    echo $name;
    ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
    <?php
    echo 'https://goo.gl/2QvRXf';
    ?>
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope it helps!