# 100% height div isnt working in Chrome when i print it

Tags: html, height

I want to write a div for every print page. So i did height of div 100%. Normally in every browser it is working well. But when i print this page it is not working in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTL>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">    
<title>Brove.NET ISO Yazılımı</title>
<style>
html,body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;   
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.sayfa{
    height: 100%;   
    width: 768px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="sayfa" style="background-color:#666666">fds</div>
<div class="sayfa" style="background-color:#cccccc">fds</div>
<div class="sayfa" style="background-color:#aaaaaa">fds</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is solution, man...

Try this code that is

```
@media print and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
.sayfa{
    height: 1101px;
    width: 768px;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the width and height of your html and body elements to 100%:

```
<style>

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS/Chrome issue has been gone over here:

[height 100% in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3124394/441574)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I can't find any documentation on this bug, but it's definitely a bug, no doubt about it.

Your code will execute perfectly in non-Webkit browsers (I'm assuming Safari does the same thing) and shows up fine on the screen, then goes into a magic can of fail upon clicking print, right? What's a guy to do?

Answer, give the HTML and BODY tags a defined height in an "actual" measurement, not percents:

```
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   /* etc */

   height: 880px;       
}

div.sayfa {
   height: 33%;
}
```

The pages print the same from Firefox 14 and Chrome 19+ using the styles above.

My experiments yielded a printed-page height of 880 pixels for the printer we were using, your mileage will probably vary. EMs work, too, but that caused too many headaches, so I figure a definitive pixel value would work best.

It's a messy workaround, but at least it *actually* works.